# Highcharts - Display Stack Label

Tags: highcharts

I want to create a chart like this

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa964128.moressrschartsfig01c(l=en-US,v=sql.90).gif

But the chart is in Microsoft Reporting and I want is in DotnetHighcharts.

When I search in Highcharts Demo, I found one similar chart but there's no group label (Male, Female).

http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-stacked-and-grouped

Comment: this is as far as I can explore http://jsfiddle.net/pMA2H/155/ but need to create another empty series and assign value false to showInLegend. I have hard time to do it because the chart is program in c# and no ShowInlegend properties plus all series and categories are dynamic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Black Label has come out with Highcharts plugin for grouped categories.

See here https://github.com/blacklabel/grouped_categories/

Answer (score 1):

There are many examples about highcharts groupped categories

[Example1](http://jsfiddle.net/9WUQy/3/)

[Example2](http://jsfiddle.net/g87AE/3/)

[Example3](http://jsfiddle.net/hfrntt/pMA2H/3/)

define categories

```
xAxis: [{
    categories: ['Australia', 'Germany', 'Australia', 'Germany'],
```

assing category to group

```
data: [['Group1', 20],['Group1',30],['Group2', 35],['Group2', 25]]
},
```

Comment: Oh my god.. I just found this today. This is exactly what I want. I found this using your keyword "highcharts grouped categories". All this while I use different term to search. https://github.com/blacklabel/grouped_categories

Comment: Before I found that, your Example1 and Example2 are good enough.

Answer (score 1):

Refer this link:

[highcharts column labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12197047/highcharts-column-labels)

See the categories part in the fiddle below they have show the very good example of what you need:

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/WQjVP/3/)

use this

```
xAxis: {
    categories: ["Location A","Location B","Location C"],
    title: {
        text: "Location"

    }
},
```

or this

```
xAxis: [{
categories: [{
name: 'fruits'
children: ['orange', 'mango']
},{
name: 'birds'
children: ['eagle', 'parrot']
}]
}]
```

hope this might help you.